# Change the values of all the values in a table with bookedmarked javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code contained within a bookmark that I was hoping to run on any webpage with a table to change all the values contained with in the td elements. The idea being that I can do it just by clicking the bookmark. Any idea why it's not working or if it can work at all?

Ultimately what I am trying to do is a bit more complex than this but I trying to solve my problem piece by piece.

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  anchors[i].value = "test";
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<td>` elements do not have a `.value`. Instead, you're looking to change [`anchors[i].innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

```js
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  anchors[i].innerHTML = "test";
};
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is the same true for < a >?

Comment: No problem, and yes. `.value` is reserved for things that have a user input (most commonly form elements). That's tags like `<input>` and `<textarea>`. For almost everything else you'll want `.innerHTML` (or `.textContent`) :)